# MeekroDB error "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: php, mysql, meekro

I have a PHP script with the following lines:

```
require_once 'meekrodb.2.1.class.php';
DB::$user = 'usr';
DB::$password = 'pwd';
DB::$dbName = 'db';
DB::$encoding = 'utf8';

$results = DB::queryFirstField("
    CALL getSequence('time_id', %i); // ***** Stored procedure call *****
", TENANT_ID);

DB::insert('timeentry', array(
    'tenant_id' => TENANT_ID,
    'time_id' => $results,
    'timestart' => DB::sqleval("now()"),
    'assig_id' => $assig_id
));
```

I am getting the following error:

> QUERY: INSERT INTO `timeentry` (`tenant_id`, `time_id`, `timestart`, `assig_id`) VALUES (1, '42', now(), '1')
>
> ERROR: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

If I replace the call to the stored procedure with a SELECT statement, everything works fine.

```
$results = DB::queryFirstField("
    SELECT 45; // ***** SELECT statement *****
");

DB::insert('timeentry', array(
    'tenant_id' => TENANT_ID,
    'time_id' => $results,
    'timestart' => DB::sqleval("now()"),
    'assig_id' => $assig_id
));
```

I have not analyzed the internals of the MeekroDB Library (http://www.meekro.com).

I tried wrapping each statement in a transaction but I get the same error when COMMIT is executed right after the call to the stored procedure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls to stored procedures in MySQL produce multiple result sets.  That is, a stored proc *might* have more than one SELECT, so the client has to iterate through several result sets to finish processing the CALL.

See examples in the answer to this question: [Retrieving Multiple Result sets with stored procedure in php/mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683794/retrieving-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedure-in-php-mysqli)

Until all results from the CALL are finished, it isn't considered closed, and MySQL does not permit you to run another query before the current query is completely finished.

I don't know the MeekroDB library well, but glancing at the online docs I don't see any way to iterate through multiple result sets.  So there may not be any way to call stored procedures safely.  I suggest you contact the author for specific support:  http://www.meekro.com/help.php.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your answer, how can I know for sure if the stored procedure is getting one or more result sets. I have executed it in a MySQL client and I only get one result... it is probably a MeekroDB bug. I have already contacted the author. Can I execute a command (outside this library) in order to close the pending query?

Comment: I managed to close the connection by altering the library. Thanks for your help. Of course I hope to get the official fix for this issue.

Comment: Even if a given stored proc returns only one result set, call it invokes the multi-query interface.  This is probably just an API usage that the MeekroDB developer didn't anticipate.  Yes, you can close the statement, or you can call `while ($pdoStmt->nextRowset()) { }` to force it to iterate to the end of the chain of results.  See also http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php