# get records from procedure having multiple select statements in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure in mysql having multiple select statements in it.

Here is my code :

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `databasename`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `wholeProjectDetails`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`databasename`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `wholeProjectDetails`(IN givenpid INT)
BEGIN
select * from projects where projectid=givenpid;
select * from projects where projectid<>givenpid;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

When i called this procedure using statement :

```
call wholeProjectDetails(2);
```

it is displaying only first statement's results, i want that it will display both statement's records.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If 'PHP' then, follow [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1686047/767881)

Answer (score 0):

When you call this procedure, MySQL creates two result-sets. Now, you need to get these two result-sets using your MySQL client. Read information about client you use, does it support this feature? For example, in .NET you can use [IDataReader.NextResult Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in mysqli - [mysqli::next_result function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php), and so on.

If you want just to view these result-sets, you can install one of MySQL GUI tools, there are free ones.