# Is It possible to return Multiple tables from stored proc in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, multiple-tables

I am want to return two tables from one Stored Proc. I am not sure if it is possible or not, but it is possible in MSSQL, so, I guess it is possible in MYSQL as well.

What I want to achieve is:

```
select * from table1;
select * from table2;
```

result in dataset of two tables. As I experienced till now, where MYSQL get's the first select it returns from there.

I have tried to find on Google, but I didn't find anything that works.

Comment: I can't help feeling this is half a question. - Return to what I wonder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can return as many result sets as you like.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure sp_result_sets()
begin

select * from table1;
select * from table2;

end
$$
```

Comment: how, can you please give me any example.

Comment: @RamSingh See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1686047 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62629806