# Retrieve multiple result sets from Stored Procedure with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created a stored procedure with 4 statements

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE returnFunction()
BEGIN
        SELECT
            * 
        FROM
            tb_1 as 1;

        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tb_2 as 2;
            
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tb_3 as 3;
            
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tb_4 as 4;
END;
```

And call this sp like this

```
$query = "CALL returnFunction()";
$p_sql = connection::conn()->prepare($query);
$p_sql->execute(); 
do {
     $rows = $p_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
     if ($rows) 
     {
          print_r($rows);
     }
   } while ($p_sql->nextRowset());
```

This return all of results of statements together..

I need to take the results to first statement and put it in a variable $v1
second statement variable $v2
third statement variable $v3
fourth statement variable $v4

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543792/php-variable-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to generate variable names on the fly:

```
$query = "CALL returnFunction()";
$p_sql = connection::conn()->prepare($query);
$p_sql->execute(); 
$i = 1;
do {
     $rows = $p_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
     if ($rows) 
     {
          print_r($rows);
          ${"v$i"} = $rows;
     }
     $i++;
} while ($p_sql->nextRowset());
```

This will put each non-empty result set in a variable `$v1`, `$v2` etc. But you should consider just using an array instead:

```
$query = "CALL returnFunction()";
$p_sql = connection::conn()->prepare($query);
$p_sql->execute(); 
$v = array();
do {
     $rows = $p_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
     if ($rows) 
     {
          print_r($rows);
          $v[] = $rows;
     }
} while ($p_sql->nextRowset());
```

Note that if you want to store the empty result sets too then move the assignment outside of the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use union like below and output v1,v2,v3,v4 and then assign them to your variables

```
SELECT MAX(v1) as v1,MAX(v2) as v2,MAX(v3) as v3,MAX(v4) as v4
FROM
(       
SELECT 1.x AS v1,NULL  AS v2,NULL AS v3, NULL AS v4 
FROM tb_1 AS 1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS v2,2.x  AS v2,NULL AS v3, NULL AS v4
FROM tb_2 AS 2
UNION ALL    
SELECT NULL AS v2,NULL AS v2,3.x AS v3, NULL AS v4
FROM tb_3 AS 3
UNION ALL    
SELECT NULL AS v2,NULL AS v2,NULL AS v3, 4.x AS v4
FROM tb_4 AS 4
) A
```